# Why google play showing support for just 40 to 45 percent devices

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I have searched through the google but could not find any reason why google play showing support for only 45% devices it support to 90 to 92 percent devices on the play store

here my manifest permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

but google play showing some extra permissions am also wondering why play store showing this

[image]

Also i have a question that can google play filtering apps on camera flash or flash light availability?

any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a library that uses those other features. In particular, it looks as though you have a library that uses the camera and thus adds the camera, microphone, flash, and autofocus features.

You can easily identify the library that is adding these features by looking at the manifest merger report generated by Gradle. This is located at app/build/outputs/logs. The manifest merger report text file there will list out every manifest element pulled in from different manifest files and which file they came from.

If you truly do not require those features, you can declare your own `<uses-feature>` elements with the `android:required` attribute set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the following to your manifest, please change the required in order of your functionalities:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"     
     android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" 
     android:required="false" />
```

Also, why is your api lvl 16+? If you switch to 15+ you will have a lot of more devices.

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html API users are only 1.9%, API 16 is probably a good SDK version to target.

Comment: many thanks for reply but why google play is showing camra flash

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani I dont think that 1.9% is a low number. In 1 millon its 19k that u are missing.

Comment: @Naveedumar you are not asking for flash in your app? Any external lib?

Comment: @JpCrow, I wouldn't dismiss 1.9%, but that percentage would probably come down in the near future. So for most new apps, I think API 16 would suffice (especially considering the fact that 4.1 introduced a lot of very important features that did not exist before).

Comment: jpCrow yes i was using a external lib which acquire flash permission and thanks to @Tanis.7x helps to figure out the manifest merger log file, so now can you suggest me how can i mark all other permission as not required?